Select a field from a table and the values of a table-returning UDF related to that field
I have a function which returns a table with a single row.
Basically this table stores information about a string like:
|IsPrintable|OriginalString|CleanString|
Let's assume a table with two columns with strings
|colA|colB|
I don't manage to select both columns + the IsPrintable from the function applied on colB
|colA|colB|IsPrintable|
something like
SELECT colA, colB, (SELECT IsPrintable FROM UDF_My_Function(colB)) FROM MyTable

I know I could rewrite the function so it returns a value but for other purposes it is practical that it returns a table so I would like to avoid it

You use cross apply, something like: select m.*, f.* from mytable m cross apply dbo.UDF_My_Function(colB) f

You use cross apply, something like:
select m.*, f.* from 
mytable m 
cross apply dbo.UDF_My_Function(colB) f


This of course worked
Thank you
